# A/B testing in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to implement landing pages in wordpress with A/B testing.

So each landing page should have two versions A and B. So if you visit landing page you should in 50% cases get version A and in other 50% cases should get version B.

So on 100 visits 50 times should be served version A and 50 times should be served version B. And of course one URL should serve both versions.

I started with this:

I have two custom post types: "landing-main" and "landing-versions".

The main page will be saved as "landing-main" post type and will have post meta fields which will contain ID's of A and B versions. A and B versions will be two different posts saved as "landing-versions" custom post type.

So I create version A and version B:

```
$args = array(
  'post_title'    => 'Version A',
  'post_content'  => 'Content of Version A',
  'post_status'   => 'publish', 
  'post_type'     => 'landing-versions',
 );

 $versionA_ID = wp_insert_post($args);

$args = array(
  'post_title'    => 'Version B',
  'post_content'  => 'Content of Version B',
  'post_status'   => 'publish', 
  'post_type'     => 'landing-versions',
 );

 $versionB_ID = wp_insert_post($args);
```

Then create the main post:

```
$args = array(
  'post_title'    => 'Main Post',
  'post_content'  => '',
  'post_status'   => 'publish', 
  'post_type'     => 'landing-main',
 );

 $main_ID = wp_insert_post($args);
```

Then add post meta to save versions A and B of main post:

```
add_post_meta($main_ID, 'first_version', $versionA_ID);
add_post_meta($main_ID, 'second_version', $versionB_ID);
```

Now suppose that URL of main post is:

```
www.mysite.com/?p=1
```

When you wisit this URL I want in 50% show content of version A and in 50% content of version B:

So I will add hook on conntent:

```
add_filter( 'the_content', 'changePostContent');

function changePostContent($content){
    global $post;
    if($post->post_type == 'landing-main'){

        $versionA_ID =get_post_meta($post->ID,'first_version',true);
        $versionB_ID =get_post_meta($post->ID,'second_version',true);

        $versionA = get_post($versionA_ID);
        $versionB = get_post($versionB_ID);

        $versionA_Content = $versionA->post_content;
        $versionB_Content = $versionB->post_content;

        // in 50% return $versionA_Content;
        // in 50% return $versionB_Content;
    }
}
```

So have anyone idea how to implement this part, in 50% return content of version A and in 50% return content of version B. Or this could be changed, fore example: in 70% return content of version A and in 30% return content of version B. So on 100 visits 70 times should be served content of version and and in other 30% should be returned content of version B

Comment: quick/dirty/ugly: `if (rand(0,1)) { showA(); } else { showB(); }`

Comment: yeap but this will not be exactly 50/50. For example rand(0,1) can three times return number greater than 0.5 and only once lower than 0.5. So on 4 visits I will get 3 time verion A and 1 time version B

Comment: It would easily even out if your site has enough visitors. With a really small visitor base your A/B testing results don't mean much anyway.

Comment: Those number are just for example, of course that site will have more visitors.

Comment: @masca: So what? that's basic statistics. If you have only 4 visitors, then your a/b testing is utterly pointless. rand(0,1) will generate roughly 50:50 split between `0` and `1` over a **LARGE** sample.

Comment: you could do a counter in the database somewhere......divide by 2 if even - a if odd b

Comment: shouldn't the a/b testing be done per user, not visit? for example, user 1 always gets a, user 2 always gets b, and so on?

Answer (score 0):

Never tried this, but here I go answering:

I'm a fan of the first comment above `if (rand(0,1)) { showA(); } else { showB(); }` but you've indicated that's too random.

You could set an option so everytime the site is hit it shows the other page, and use cookies to prevent users getting served a different page if they hit their back button.  Following example uses a function landing_page() that accepts the page as an argument.

```
if(isset($_COOKIE['landing_page'])) {
    landing_page( $_COOKIE['landing_page'] );
}
else {
  $landing_page = get_option( 'landing_page');

  if ( $landing_page == 'a') {
      landing_page( 'b' );
      update_option( 'landing_page', 'b' );
      setcookie('landing_page' ,'b',time()+3600*24*30 );
  } 
  else {
      landing_page( 'a' );
      update_option( 'landing_page', 'a' );
      setcookie('landing_page' ,'a',time()+3600*24*30 );
  }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use a database variable to get exactly 50%...

```
$which_page = get_option( 'which_page', '' );
// Catch for the first time the script is ever run...
if( empty( $which_page ) ) {
    update_option( 'which_page', 'show_b' );
    show_a();
// Catch to call show_a() function
}elseif( $which_page == 'show_a' ) {
    update_option( 'which_page', 'show_b' );
    show_a();
// Catch to call show_b() function
}else {
    update_option( 'which_page', 'show_a' );
    show_b();
}
```

If you needed to alter this to work with 70% / 30% (or whatever), then you'll need to set another option for 'which_page_count' and store the number of times the page is visited... then do a quick calculation on the count to know when to switch between the two functions...